# Is it possible to get values from an API? (HTML)

Tags: html, api, numbers, weather

I'm trying to make a little weather project, and I am using this API for Toronto weather = https://weather.gc.ca/wxlink/wxlink.html?cityCode=on-143&lang=e
does anyone know how I can fetch the values in the api and put it into a header?

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://weather.gc.ca/business/index_e.html), it seems like they don't have a *proper* API, but you still have 2 relatively good options:

1. Embed the page you link to into your HTML. It can be done like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <h1>Weather App</h1>
        <p style="font-size: 1.45rem">Check the wather forecast for today:</p>
        <!-- Begin WeatherLink Fragment -->
        <iframe title="Environment Canada Weather" width="287px" height="191px" src="https://weather.gc.ca/wxlink/wxlink.html?cityCode=on-143&amp;lang=e" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        <!-- End WeatherLink Fragment -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you need more fine-grain control over data, you have the second option.

2. RSS feed

This option is also much harder. You can't make request from client side since the site we're trying to read doesn't set the needed header. This way, you will only be able to read it from the server.

You don't specify if your app has backend (if any), but to accomplish this particular task it has to.

Here is a node.js snippet that extracts the needed data:

```
const https = require('https');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const parser = new xml2js.Parser();

const throwError = message => {
    throw new Error(message);
};

/**
 * Extracts YYYY-MM-DD from YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
 * 
 * @param {Date | string} date Date object or ISO string
 * 
 * @returns {string} YYYY-MM-DD part of ISO date
 */
const getISODate = (date) => {
    if (typeof date === 'string') {
        return date.split('T')[0];
    }
    return date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
};

/**
 * Gets XML atom feed from https://weather.gc.ca/,
 * parses it, and extracts the needed data.
 *
 * @see https://weather.gc.ca/business/index_e.html
 * @see https://weather.gc.ca/rss/city/on-143_e.xml 
 *
 * @returns {void} nothing
 */
const getTorontoWeather = () => {
    // Make https request
    https.get('https://weather.gc.ca/rss/city/on-143_e.xml', (res) => {
        const { statusCode } = res;
        if (statusCode !== 200) { // Ok range might be broader
            throwError('Request failed');
        }

        res.setEncoding('utf8');

        let rawXMLString = '';
        // Add a chunk of data at a time to the total
        res.on('data', chunk => rawXMLString += chunk);
        res.on('end', () => { // Finished reading data
            parser.parseString(rawXMLString, (err, res) => {
                if (err) {
                    throwError('XML parsing failed');
                }

                // Object that represents entire feed
                const feed = res.feed;
                const today = getISODate(new Date());
                // Find today entries
                const todayEntries = feed.entry.filter((entry) => {
                    return (
                        getISODate(entry.updated[0]) === today &&
                        entry.category.find(category => category.$.term === 'Current Conditions')
                    );
                })

                console.log(todayEntries);
            });

        });
    }).on('error', () => {
        throwError('Request failed');
    })
};

getTorontoWeather();
```

It uses [xml2js library](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js) to parse XML.

Now, when you have data prepared on the back end you could either:

1. Render the entire page with some templating engine (requires quite a complex setup).
2. Make a request to your entrypoint from the client (easier).

**UPD**:
Or you can fetch the RSS feed with [cors-anywhere](https://weather.gc.ca/business/index_e.html) and use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to parse it.